Creating a new column based on condition in R
I have this dataframe in R:
df <- data.frame(
  srr = c("sampleA", "sampleB", "sampleC", "sampleD"),
  position = c(16, 16, 16, 16),
  refBase = c("G", "G", "G", "G"),
  altBase = c("G", "C", "A", "T")
)

I want to create a new column (genoType) based on the following conditions: if altBase is equal to refBase, add "0/0"; if it is different, add "0/1"; if it is different from refBase and the previous altBase observation, add "0/2";and so on...
In the end, I want my dataframe to be like this
data.frame(
  srr = c("sampleA", "sampleB", "sampleC", "sampleD"),
  position = c(16, 16, 16, 16),
  refBase = c("G", "G", "G", "G"),
  altBase = c("G", "C", "A", "T"),
  genoType = c("0/0","0/1","0/2","0/3")
)

I've tried this, but it didn't work:
df <- df %>%
  group_by(srr, position, refBase) %>%
  mutate(
    new_col = case_when(
      altBase == refBase ~ "0/0",
      !duplicated(altBase) ~ "0/1",
      duplicated(altBase) ~ "0/2",
      TRUE ~ "0/3"
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup()


I think it might help to make your example larger. What would happen if the following two rows had a match and then a non-match? Would you expect "0/0" and "0/1", or something else?

Perhaps something like df |> mutate(dif = refBase != altBase, group = cumsum(dif & !lag(dif))) |> mutate(new_col = paste0("0/", cumsum(dif)), .by = group)? That would reset at 0/0 with each match, and then count up 0/1 0/2 0/3 etc like you describe with non-matching rows.

When you use group_by(srr, position, refBase) you are saying you don't want to be able to compare across rows from different groups. But from your description you want to look at previous observations. So this group_by is preventing you from doing that.

Clarify how does this make biological sense? Why are we reformatting genotype based on different sample?

You can use cumsum to create the groups where they are equal, and then use that group to create another cumsum when they are not equal:
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, grp=cumsum(altBase==refBase)) |>
  mutate(genoType=paste0("0/", cumsum(altBase!=refBase)), .by=grp)     


      srr position refBase altBase grp genoType
1 sampleA       16       G       G   1      0/0
2 sampleB       16       G       C   1      0/1
3 sampleC       16       G       A   1      0/2
4 sampleD       16       G       T   1      0/3

This should also work on a larger sample, say df2 shown below:
      srr position refBase altBase
1 sampleA       16       G       G
2 sampleB       16       G       C
3 sampleC       16       G       A
4 sampleD       16       G       T
5 sampleE       16       G       G
6 sampleF       16       G       C
7 sampleG       16       G       G
8 sampleH       16       G       G


mutate(df2, grp=cumsum(altBase==refBase)) |>
   mutate(genoType=paste0("0/", cumsum(altBase!=refBase)), .by=grp)


      srr position refBase altBase grp genoType
1 sampleA       16       G       G   1      0/0
2 sampleB       16       G       C   1      0/1
3 sampleC       16       G       A   1      0/2
4 sampleD       16       G       T   1      0/3
5 sampleE       16       G       G   2      0/0
6 sampleF       16       G       C   2      0/1
7 sampleG       16       G       G   3      0/0
8 sampleH       16       G       G   4      0/0

You can also include the srr column in your .by if required, as you hinted at in your attempt.

Data:
df2 <- structure(list(srr = c("sampleA", "sampleB", "sampleC", "sampleD", 
"sampleE", "sampleF", "sampleG", "sampleH"), position = c(16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16), refBase = c("G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G"), altBase = c("G", "C", "A", "T", "G", "C", 
"G", "G")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

